# Ways to arrange 7 boys and 3 girls end positions taken by boys

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 7 boys and 3 girls be arranged if the end positions are occupied by boys and no girls are adjacent?

So I consider this arrangement:

B[GB GB GB B B]B

For the end positions you have 7 x 6.
Between them you can have 5! x 2 arrangements
and for each of those spot, you have 3! (girls) and 5! (boys)
In all you have 7 x 6 x (5!)^2 x 3! x 2 ways to arrange them. Am I doing right? Thanks.

Comment: "For the end positions you have $7\color{red}{!}\times 6\color{red}{!}$... that seems *waaaay* too large.  How many ways can you pick who stands on the far left?  $7$ ways or $7!$ ways?  "Am I doing right" no.

Comment: Where are all of these factorials coming from? If you pick one of $7$ boys to go in front, there are $7$ ways to do that, not $7!=5040$. I'd approach by permuting the boys first. Then you permute the three girls and you have to see how many ways you can place them such that each girl is in between two boys.

Comment: My bad, that should be 7 x 6 not 7! x 6!

Comment: @JMoravitz I editted it already. Sorry. Is it all fine now?

Comment: So you have $5!$ from permuting the three $GB$ pairs and two single boys, but you also have $5!$ from permuting the boys? If you've already ordered the boys once, it's double counting to then permute them a second time.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be multiplying numbers without thinking about what the numbers actually represent or why we would want to multiply things in the first place.

Here is a corrected approach for multiplication principle:

- Arrange the boys in a line without the girls.  Give a little bit of extra space between the boys so that girls might fit inbetween them later if they choose to.
- Pick which empty space between the boys the youngest girl stands in
- Pick which empty space between the boys the second youngest girl stands in
- Pick which empty space between the boys the oldest girl stands in.  (*Remember, we cannot pick to the left of the left-most boy or to the right of the right-most boy and we cannot pick the same empty space for more than one girl*)

Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

---

Alternate approach avoiding "*empty spaces leftover*" (*which I think isn't an appropriate reason to avoid the earlier method*)

- Pick which arrangement of `gggbbbbb` is used for the center eight people where no two `g`'s are adjacent.  *Note:* In this step we have not yet decided *which* boy each `b` represents etc... we are merely deciding on the *pattern* that the central boys and girls take
- Arrange the $7$ boys in a line
- Arrange the $3$ girls in a line
- Have the boys and girls merge their two lines where the center eight positions follow the same boy-girl pattern selected in step 1.

To count how many ways step 1 can be accomplished we must break into two cases: either the last position is occupied by a boy, or the last position is occupied by a girl.

If the last position is occupied by a boy, we can arrange three *identical* copies of `gb` and two *identical* copies of `b` to describe the arrangement.

> This is the same as selecting a subset of size three from a set of size five and can be accomplished in $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ ways.  This seems similar to your approach in your original post, however you did not seem to account correctly for the fact that the objects being arranged are identical.

If the last position is occupied by a girl, we can arrange two copies of `gb` and three copies of `b` to describe the arrangement of the first seven positions and `g` occupies the eighth position.

Apply the addition principle and continue with the rest of the problem, eventually applying multiplication principle and concluding.

Comment: I find it hard to visualize the number of ways in which the 3 girls can take the 6 vacant spaces between the boys. I always prefer the approach wherein no extra spaces are left unoccupied, that is, the number of ways to arrange those 8 people inside the 2 positions taken by boys.

Comment: @PanchixRegen added an alternate approach, but the first method really is simpler to me and requires less arithmetic, even avoiding binomial coefficients or division.  The second approach I give requires the use of binomial coefficients (*or tedious brute force*) and addition principle.  You could also instead count the number of arrangements in step1 using stars-and-bars, but again this seems overkill.  I would recommend getting over your mental block and accept the first method.  The "extra spaces left unoccupied" won't matter because once everyone is in their place they can slide closer.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Select 2 boys you want at the end, and permute them in 7C2 * 2! ways.

2.Now you have 5 boys and 3 girls remaining with 6 vacant spaces between the boys. You can arrange these boys in 5! ways.

3.Now you can choose 3 of the 6 vacant spaces for 3 girls and arrange them in 6C3 * 3! ways.

Final answer = 7C2 * 2! * 5! * 6C3*3!
                         = 7! * 3! * 6C3.